# How to check self-signed certificate from URL

Tags: java, ssl, websecurity

How can i check that certificate from given URL is self-signed (like browser does)

```
URL destinationURL = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) destinationURL.openConnection();
conn.connect();
Certificate[] certs = conn.getServerCertificates();
```

But only thing i found is checkValidity(Date d). Which is working fine, but that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a relevant *Red Hat* article.

*[Red Hat – Who signed my cert? | Enable Sysadmin](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/who-signed-my-cert)*.

> *"... A certificate is self-signed if the subject and issuer match. A certificate is signed by a Certificate Authority (CA) if they are different. ..."*

You can utilize the *[X509Certificate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html)* class, which offers the *[getSubjectX500Principal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getSubjectX500Principal())*, and *[getIssuerX500Principal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getIssuerX500Principal())* methods.

Comment: Make sense. Checked on some different pages. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the next

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.IOException;

public class GetRequest {

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

    public String doRequest() throws IOException {
        httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        StringBuilder dto = new StringBuilder();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://test.example.com");

        // add request headers
        request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "UTF-8");

        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request)) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                // return it as a String
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                dto.append(result);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.prinstracke();

        }
        return dto.toString();
    }

    public void closeClient() throws IOException {
        this.httpClient.close();
    }
}
```

If you get one exception, due it is not valid or self-signed